# I have trouble figuring out how to come up with a menu like this one on Truedialer

Tags: android, listactivity

I am developing an app where I have several items in a list and I want to show a menu like in truedialer whereby it pull from the bottom of the screen but does not fill.  When I drag it upwards it can still fill the screen..
I have the menu items in an stand alone activity.
Can Someone help me figure out how o have to activity with the menus behave like the one of truedialer as shown in the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoleO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRzL5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using bottom sheets

https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html